# Adding several ListFieldIterators in one Page does not work as expected

Tags: development, display-form

I tried to display several ListItems, each with a ListFieldIterator, but all the LFIs display the same Item (the first one assigned). Is there a way to have each Iterator Display the Item it got assigned? Or is this a bug/not possible? I have to do it in code, I haven't tested if it works when declaring each LFI in the ASPX file.

This is my code

```
foreach (var article in articles)
{
    count++;
    ListFieldIterator lfi = new ListFieldIterator();
    lfi.ListId = listId;
    lfi.ID = "lfi_" + count;
    lfi.ItemId = article.Article.Id.Value;
    lfi.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
    ArticlesPanel.Controls.Add(lfi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a development machine at my disposal right now, but this might be related to not disposing the ListFieldIterator.

Try something like this, though I cannot guarantee that it'll fix it:

```
using (ListFieldIterator lfi = new ListFieldIterator())
{
    lfi.ListId = listId;
    lfi.ItemId = article.Article.Id.Value;
    lfi.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
    ArticlesPanel.Controls.Add(lfi);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately it did not work. But you got my hopes high for a few minutes :)
Well I had to solve it differently now. I iterate over every item and build the controls in code. Still it would interest me if it is possible to have several ListFieldIterators.